# How to select data from one table using other fields of another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two table, I want to perform select operation from one table using one key fields of another.

```
--------                --------
table_1                  table_2
--------                --------
id                      id
name                    data2
data1                   data3
--------                data4
                        data5
                        table1_id(FK)
                        --------------
```

I try to select data from `table_2` using `data1` of `table_1`

I attempt this statement but give a result of empty

```
SELECT data2, data3, data4
FROM table_2
INNER JOIN table_1 on table_1.data1 = table_2.table1_id
WHERE data1.table_1=? and data5.table_2=?
```

How to make this statement?

Comment: Shouldn't the join be `INNER JOIN table_1 on table_1.id = table_2.table1_id`? Also, the where clause doesn't make much sense as it seems you've switched table and column names. Could you add som sample data and expected output to clarify what it is you want to accomplish?

Comment: and it should be `where table_1.data1=.. and table_2.data5=..`

Comment: @jpw thank you, i can get the result. As i am new so i cant make good database design. I try to use this query in my web service api using php.

Answer (score 0):

Your JOIN condition and your WHERE condition looks strange:

Try this:

```
SELECT data2, data3, data4
  FROM table_2
 INNER 
  JOIN table_1 ON table_1.id = table_2.table1_id
 WHERE table_1.data1 = ? AND table_2.data5 = ?
```

Comment: table_2.data5 in where clause

Answer (score 0):

You should join tables by their primary and foreign keys and write Table Name first before Column Name

```
SELECT data2, data3, data4
FROM table_2
INNER JOIN table_1
   on table_1.id = table_2.table1_id
WHERE table_1.data1=? and table_2.data5=?
```